# What are applicative effects?

Tags: haskell, applicative

What is the meaning of the concept of *effect* in *effectful applicative programming*?

For example, which parts of expressions below are the *effects*?

```
[(+1)] <*> [2,3]
Just (+1) <*> Nothing
```

Comment: I doubt these terms are used in the Haskell standard. It might be helpful to hear/read them in the context you have.

Comment: Those show typical usage of Applicative Functors in regular pure computations. Maybe looking at them in context of real world events would clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Much confusion was caused by the unfortunate choice of names, as is quite common in Haskell (think "`return`", much better named "`emit`").

`pure x` is not pure, it is `x` that is pure, `pure` is just *inject*. It was [envisioned to be used in `pure f <*> a <*> b <*> ...`](http://strictlypositive.org/IdiomLite.pdf) pattern, letting us effectfully apply a pure function `f`.<sup>(1)</sup>

`[]` applicative<sup>(2)</sup>  lets us *"non-deterministically" apply* (`<*>`, not `$`) *a* non-deterministic value (not *two values*, in your example) to a non-deterministic function; the *non-determinism* is the effect.<sup>(3)</sup>

In list applicative, `[(+1), (+2)]` is *a* non-deterministic function that might increment a value by 1, and also might increment it by 2. `[3,4,5]` is a non-deterministic value whose possible values are as listed. Just as we apply normal entities `(+1)` and `3` normally, with `(+1) $ 3` , so can we apply non-deterministic values *non-deterministically*, with `[(+1)] <*> [3]` or `[(+1),(+2)] <*> [3,4,5]`.

And with `Maybe` the *possibility of failure* is the effect.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> as the paper says, in Introduction: *"we collect the values of some effectful computations, which we then use as the arguments to a pure function `(:)`"*

<sup>(2)</sup> `[]` by itself is not an applicative, `([], pure :: a -> [a], (<*>) :: [a -> b] -> [a] -> [b])` is an applicative, given some (lawful) implementations of `pure` and `(<*>)`. For the `[]` functor, there are two possibilities: an outer product-like of the standard `[]` `Applicative` instance, and an inner product-like one of the `ZipList`'s.

<sup>(3)</sup> `x` is pure (as in, "Haskell is pure"); `pure x` stands for an  effectful computation producing `x` without actually having any *additional* effect. "without an effect" refers to the law of `pure x *> u == u` i.e. `pure x` doesn't add any effect into the combined computation on top of `u`'s contribution. But the possibility of effect is there. *(One example is an idempotent side effect, like triggering an existence of a certain file in a file system: `pure ()` by itself would also perform this effect; `(pure id <*>) == id` still holds, as it should.)*

`pure 7 :: IO Int` is certainly not the pure (as in, "Haskell is pure") value `7`, it is the pure value `7` in an effectful context (here, *`IO`*). Even if it does no actual action in that context, it is still *in* that context (*`IO`*).

On the other hand, and unrelated to the purpose of `pure`, of course *any* Haskell value is "pure" i.e. referentially transparent. `getLine` is a pure, referentially transparent Haskell *value*. It *stands for / denotes* an effectful I/O *computation*, getting an input line from a user and producing it as the result to be used by the next I/O computation in a chain.

`print 7` is a pure referentially transparent Haskell value. That's not a kind of "pure" that is meant here. `[1,2]` is a pure value, but seen from another perspective, *interpreted* by the `[]` implementation of `<*> / pure`, it's treated as a nondeterministic value with two possible pure values `1` and `2`. Same for `[1] = pure 1`. It can still be interpreted as a nondeterministic value with one possible pure value, `1`.

`[1,2] *> [10,20]` = `[10,20,10,20]` ; `[1] *> [10,20]` = `[10,20]`. So unlike `[1,2]`, `[1]` doesn't add any more nondeterminism into the nondeterministic computation described / denoted by `[10,20]` (under the standard `[]` `Applicative` implementation). But it's still a nondeterministic value; it can participate in `*>`, unlike `1` which can't.

*We know a type by kinds of interactions it can participate in.*

See also:

- [*values* and *computations*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891)

Comment: I like your explanation for where `pure` got its name.

Comment: If I undertand @luqui's answer correctly, `pure x` is indeed a pure, referentially transparent value.

Comment: of course any Haskell value is pure and referentially transparent. `getLine` is a pure, referentially transparent Haskell value. `print 7` is a pure referentially transparent Haskell value. that's not a kind of "pure" that is meant here. `[1,2]` is a pure value, but seen from another angle it's a nondeterministic value with two possible pure values `1` and `2`. Same for `[1]`. It can still be interpreted as a nondeterministic value with one possible pure value, `1`.

Comment: So `pure x` puts a pure `x` into an effectful context without actually performing this effect, So far my intuition of pure was "creates a most minimal context". But I think "creates the possibility of an effect" is more accurate and more natural. And a pure effectful context must not be confused with purity with respect to values. Your comments are very educational and deserve to be part of the answer.

Comment: @bob thanks, when I have time. :) should also link that pigworker's do-notation answer, making same distinctions between "values" and "computations" (BTW he's Conor McBride, one of the authors of that Applicative paper, did you know that?). or if you want, you could edit as well...

Comment: @IvenMarquardt I've edited to mention the possibility of an idempotent effect (a trigger of some kind), where `pure ()` would actually have a side effect.

Answer (score 8):

In the FP world, an effect is any type constructor such as `Maybe`, `[]`, `IO`, etc. Effects are not to be confused with side-effects. Intuitively, an effect is an additional property of the value you're computing. `Maybe Int` means that your program calculates an `Int` with a failure effect, or `[Int]` means that your program calculates an `Int` but with a non-deterministic effect (a non-deterministic result is here modeled as a list of possible results).

Going from here, we have the terms *applicative effects* and *monadic effects*, which mean that the said effects have `Applicative` and `Monad` instances.

I can't find any authoritative information for this, it's just what I have gleaned in my experience.

Comment: `[]` by itself is not an effect, `([], pure::a->[a], (<*>)::[a->b]->[a]->[b])` is an effect, given some implementations of `pure` and `(<*>)`.

Comment: @WillNess why do you call it just an effect and not an _applicative_ effect? In my experience, any type constructor of kind `* -> *` is called an effect, without any mention of `Applicative` or `Monad`.

Comment: "applicative" is implied here. :) I meant "effect" as in the context of this question about applicatives. Without `pure` and `<*>` (or `return` and `>>=`) implementations in mind, what *is* the effect of `[]`?

Comment: (and I wasn't disagreeing with you, your point about the confusion between effects and side-effects is exactly right).

Comment: @WillNess as far as I'm understanding, it's not `[]` who's effectful, but rather the expression that produces a `[]`. For example the effect of `quux :: a -> [a]` is non-determinism. And there's no mention of `Applicative` or `Monad`. Same for `Maybe`. There's an expression with some effect.

Comment: @WillNess yes, I understand you're not disagreeing, I just want to clarify my thoughts by means of discussion :)

Comment: no, the effect of `quux :: a -> [a]` is zipped application. Or maybe a possible failure. Without a particular `<*>` implementation, you can't disprove me.

Comment: @WillNess not sure why you called that zipped application... but you still called it an effect, right? Anyway, I'd be happy to read any resource that goes into details about these differences.

Comment: yes, an effect - a *different* one. Like [`ZipList a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:ZipList) has. *Not* non-determinism. A kind of inner product, not outer product.

Answer (score 5):

We could say that an effect of type `f a` is anything that can't be written as `pure x` where `x :: a`.

In the `[]` applicative, `pure x = [x]`, so `[(+1)] = pure (+1)` probably shouldn't be considered an effect.  Similarly in the `Maybe` applicative, `pure = Just`, so `Just (+1)` is not an effect.

That leaves `[2,3]` and `Nothing` as the effects in your respective examples. This makes intuitive sense from the perspective that `[]` denotes nondeterministic computations: `[2,3]` nondeterministically chooses between 2 and 3; and the perspective that `Maybe` denotes failing computations: `Nothing` fails the computation.

The definition I used that an effect (perhaps "side-effect" would be a better word) is something that can't be written as `pure x` is just a swing at making your question precise, and does not represent any sort of consensus or standard definition.  [Will Ness's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25845511/33796) gives a different perspective, that `pure` generates an effectful computation from a pure value, which has a nice mathematical ring to it -- i.e. this definition would probably be easier to use in precise settings.

Comment: `pure x` is not pure, it is `x` that is pure. `pure x` is always an effectful `x`, by definition. `pure (+1) :: [(Num a)=>a->a]` is an effectful increment function - a *non-deterministic* increment function. The implied non-determinism *is* the effect.

Comment: I tried to expound more on what I meant, in my answer. Of course everything depends on our POV: we can see things in terms of `concatMap`, and Haskell itself is fully deterministic of course, but sometimes we prefer to think in terms of non-deterministic application. It is important also not to mix effects and side-effects, as [another answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25838314/849891) points out.

Comment: Very interesting! So, given `pure id <*> v = v` holds, there shouldn't be any side-effect performed by `pure x :: IO a` as well?

Comment: Proper question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100390/is-pure-x-io-a-a-pure-value-or-one-with-a-side-effect

Comment: @sevo re your `pure id <*> v = v` question above, maybe for `IO a`, but not in general. I've recently come up with an example of idempotent effect: say, triggering an existence of some file in a file system. then no matter how many times it is done, the effect is the same. with this effect, `(pure id <*>) == id` holds, of course, as it should, but `pure ()` does have a side effect: it creates that file if there's no such file yet. the monad (or applicative) laws only demand that the presence of `pure ()` in the computational chain changes nothing, not that it doesn't "do" anything by itself.

Answer (score 4):

Effectful applicative programming can be thought of as taking regular non-effectful computations and adding *effects* to them. These are implemented as `Applicative` instances. So while `Int` is a regular value, `A Int` is  an `Int` with some effect `A`, and `A` is an instance of `Applicative`.

Consider this expression:

```
x + y :: Int
```

This expression is not effectful; it only deals with regular, plain values, so to speak. But we can also have *effectful addition*.

One effect is *failure*; the computation may fail or succeed. If it fails, then the computation is stopped. This is simply the `Maybe` type.

```
Just (+1) <*> Nothing :: Maybe Int
```

In addition with regular values, you just add the numbers together. But now, we have addition that might *fail*. So we have to add the numbers together *provided that the computation has not failed*. We see in this expression that the computation will fail, since the second operand is `Nothing`.

If your computations can fail for more than simply one reason, you might want to have error messages that report the kind of failure that happened. Then you may use an *error* effect, which might be represented as something like `Either String` (`String` is the type of the error message). The implementation of this `Applicative` behaves similarly to the `Maybe` `Applicative`.

Another example of an effect is parsing. Parsing can be implemented by just using constructors and making them effectful. Say you want to implement a simple arithmetic language with addition and multiplication. This could be your abstract syntax tree (AST):

```
data Exp = Num Int | Var String
data AST = Add Exp Exp | Multiply Exp Exp
```

You build up the AST by simply using these constructors. But the problem is that you also need to actually parse the text, so what about the act of parsing? What about keeping track of how much of the text you have consumed? What if the parsing *fails*, because the text did not conform to your grammar? Well, in libraries like `Parsec`, that is the parsing *effect*. You use some `Parse` data type (that is an instance of `Applicative`) and lift the constructors into the effectful `Parse AST` world. Now, you can construct the AST while actually parsing the text, because the parsing is an effect added to the construction of the AST.

Notice that the `Parse` type was more complicated than both the `Maybe` and `Either String` instances; the parser has the effects of keeping track of state like how much of the input text that has been consumed, and a failed parse, which would yield an error message. `Applicative` effects can be composed together like this.