# haskell how to use previous assigned variable

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

```
  x = do
    first <- "mfwew"
    let q = first
    a <- q
    let b = a
    putStrLn (b)
    return b
```

how to use the assigned variable "first" to a <- q?

thank you

I want to do something like this

```
    do
      b <- func a
      c <- func1 b
      func2 c
```

but this won't work.  I know its because the IO type doesn't match, but is there other way to do it?
Specifically, i want to use b again in x <- xxx b.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want your code to do – your question isn't clear.  Could you elaborate, maybe with the desired result?  Relatedly, your code currently doesn't typecheck; you can't have `first <- "mfwew"` and `putStrLn (b)` in the same `do` block.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without the types of `func`, `func1` and `func2` and the expected type of the whole `do` block.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"?  That works if, for instance, `func = return`, `func1 = return . reverse`, `func2 = putStrLn`, and `a = "Hello, world!"` – it prints `!dlrow ,olleH`.  It sounds like you're having a typechecking issue, which means we need to see the specific code that doesn't typecheck in order to be helpful.

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323300/using-return-vs-not-using-return-in-the-list-monad/11326549#11326549) for some nice pictures and explanations.

Answer (score 3):

If I read your question and comments right than you want to just use the *value* of `func a` in `func1 ..` and you tried imperative `do`-style but then noticed that this only works for (the `IO`)-Monad(s).

In this case `let` comes quite close:

```
myResult a =
   let b = func a
       c = func1 b
   in func2 c
```

but in Haskell we usually do it with composition instead:

```
myResult a = func2 (func1 (func a))
```

which is

```
myResult a = func2 . func1 . func $ a
```

and finally you can drop the *point* `a` to get *point-free-style*:

```
myResult = func2 . func1 . func
```

if you like

Comment: I have to use b <- func a

Comment: why do you have to use this?

Answer (score 2):

The thumb rule is, you have to look at the type of your functions.

When a function returns `IO` (or any monad you are working in), use `<-` to run the monadic action, as in your code

```
do
  b <- func a
  c <- func1 b
  func2 c
```

When a function simply returns a value, without wrapping it in the monad, use `let`.

```
do  -- do is not really necessary here... but let's play along
  let b = func a
  let c = func1 b
  func2 c
```

Usually you need to mix both. E.g., if `func` is monadic while `func2` is not, we write

```
do
  b <- func a
  let c = func1 b
  func2 c
```

Summing up: check the type of your functions.