# When do [do x] and [do return x] evaluate differently?

Tags: haskell, monads

```
*Main> do 0
```

> 0

```
*Main> do return 0
```

> 0

```
*Main> do (Just 0)
```

> Just 0

```
*Main> do return (Just 0)
```

> Just 0

```
*Main> do Nothing
```

> Nothing

```
*Main> do return Nothing
```

> Nothing

```
bareDo :: a -> a
bareDo x = do x

doReturn :: Monad m => a -> m a
doReturn x = do return x
```

Why would `do x` and `do return x` evaluate the same, and when would they don't?

I'm trying to understand `Monad`, it has been enough tutorial and [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) there yet I couldn't figure it out.

That is even an [post](http://dev.stephendiehl.com/hask/#monads) writing

> Don't read the monad tutorials.

So, I guess getting my hand dirty might help.

I really appreciate whoever help me out of here (I mean `do` and `return`, not `Monad`. I know that would take some days).

Comment: Hint: use ghci `:t` command and find out yourself :-) i.e. `:t do 0` or `:t do return 0` have different types. In the end `do` is syntactic sugar, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323300/using-return-vs-not-using-return-in-the-list-monad

Comment: @jarandaf `do return 0 :: (Num a, Monad m) => m a`, where does `m` gone?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`do` on a single expression accomplishes nothing whatsoever: it's just a syntactic herald indicating that you *could* use action sequencing here (which would require a monad), but if you don't do that then it has just the same effect as wrapping an expression in layers of redundant parentheses.

So your example session is equivalent to this:

```
Prelude> 0
0
Prelude> return 0
0
Prelude> Just 0
Just 0
Prelude> return (Just 0)
Just 0
Prelude> Nothing
Nothing
Prelude> return Nothing
Nothing
```

Now the question is *why does `return` not accomplish anything here*. Well, actually it does, you just don't see it because GHCi is hiding implementation details. GHCi has two fundamentally different modes of interactive evaluation:

1. `IO` actions are *executed*, then the result [`print`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print)ed.
2. Everything else is `print`ed as it is.

Crucially, GHCi tries rather hard to interpret everything as an `IO` action before proceeding with 2. So if you give it an ambiguous expression like `return 0`, it notices that one possible instantiation is `IO Integer`. It immediately defaults to that, executes this side-effect free action and all you see in the result is thus `0`. This only happens for `IO` though, not for any other monads:

```
Prelude> return 0 :: IO Integer
0
Prelude> return 0 :: Maybe Integer
Just 0
Prelude> return 0 :: [] Integer
[0]
```

GHCi just happens to default to `IO` when the monad in ambiguous, but that wouldn't happen otherwise in Haskell as such.

Answer (score -1):

Good answer: never, Since `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` takes an object and puts it into a box.

Right, but unusable answer: when the x is a fixpoint of `return` from given monad.

Comment: Strictly speaking this is an answer to the converse: "when do .. and .. evaluate the *same*?"