# Haskell Put IO String

Tags: haskell, io-monad

I am trying to read and print the output from the "readProcess" command mapped onto a list of filenames:

```
files <- readProcess "ls" [] []
let mdList = map ( \file -> do
    md <- readProcess "mdls" [file] []
    return md ) $ splitOn "\n" files in
    map (\md -> putStrLn md) mdList
putStrLn "Complete"
```

Each time I try to map putStrLn onto the mdList, I get this error:

```
Couldn't match type ‘IO String’ with ‘[Char]’
```

I have read many StackOverflow answers that seem to just use putStrLn on an IO String but I am unable to do so. Also, I am new to Haskell so any other tips are also appreciated.

Comment: An `IO String` value is **not** a string. It doesn't make sense to want to put an `IO String`, for the same reason you wouldn't want to eat a cookbook.

Comment: I am aware than an IO String is not a string. I am asking how to write an IO String.

Comment: what you want `forM_`. your problem raised because you don't understand monad. you'd better try to understand what monad is in the first place.

Comment: @genghiskhan What would you expect to get when you "write" an `IO String`?  Machine code?  Assembly instructions?  What?

Comment: I don't really think the duplication is right judging from OP's intention.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr perhaps the question I've linked to doesn't quite match; by all means edit the duplicate link. This question definitely is a duplicate though; this is a common subject of confusion. The only solution is properly learning how monads work.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson Maybe I was unclear. I want to see what the value of mdList is for debugging purposes. Therefore, I through I would want to print each element in that list to stdout.

Comment: I vote to reopen. The answer to the claimed duplicate is `(<$>)`, but the answer to this question is `(>>=)` or maybe even more complicated than that. That this question is common I believe; but that particular choice of alternate question isn't a good fit.

Comment: I clearly don't have a great understanding of monads but isn't >>= equivalent to a do block?

Comment: @genghiskhan yes, it is equivalent to a `do` block. But if you shove a `do` block in a function argument, it'll always be a monadic action, not a pure value such as the function might accept.

Comment: The type of `map putStrLn` is `[String] -> [IO ()]`, but every statement in your `do` block must have type `IO X` for some `X` (and clearly `[IO ()]` can't match `IO X` for any `X`). However, `mapM_ putStrLn :: [String] -> IO ()`.

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323300/using-return-vs-not-using-return-in-the-list-monad/11326549#11326549. disregard the question, just read that answer. it's got a nice picture. *blue* is for computation descriptions (i.e. "monadic actions"), *red* (and an accidental magenta) is for values.

Comment: monad is *something* that lets you mix, under a certain discipline, the computation descriptions (with their own primitives like `putStrLn` etc.) and the pure calculations using values these computations *will* produce. that's all.

Comment: Good suggestion by Will Ness, though beware: that is discussing the _list monad_ rather than IO.

Comment: IO or [], the blue slots are treated as monadic action descriptions, and the red slots are treated as pure values, regardless. Of course IO and [] are different, but the schema for the mixing is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You are using

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

which specializes to

```
map :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> [IO b]
```

The final result, `[IO b]` is not what we need. That is a list of `IO` actions, i.e. the equivalent of a list of non-executed no-arguments imperative functions.
Instead, we want a *single* `IO` action, whose result is a list of `b`: that would be `IO [b]` instead of `[IO b]`.

The library provides that as well:

```
mapM :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
```

or, if we don't care about collecting the results

```
mapM_ :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO ()
```

The library also provides variants with flipped arguments:

```
for  :: [a] -> (a -> IO b) -> IO [b]
for_ :: [a] -> (a -> IO b) -> IO ()
```

So, the original code can be fixed as follows:

```
import Data.Foldable

files <- readProcess "ls" [] []
for_ files $ \file -> do
    md <- readProcess "mdls" [file] []
    putStrLn md
putStrLn "Complete"
```