# Why does the type match on the next line but not on the same line in `do` block?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, io-monad, do-notation

I’m reading in several lines from the input that the user has to type:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let size = 3
  arr <- replicateM size getLine
  let pairs = map parsePair arr
  print pairs
```

Why am I allowed to do `map parsePair arr` on a separate line
but not on the same line, like this:

```
arr <- map parsePair (replicateM size getLine)
```

Doing so, I get the error :

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: IO [Int]
    Actual type: [[Int]]
```

To give you more details, here is `parsePair`:

```
parsePair string = map parseInt $ words string

parseInt :: String -> Int
parseInt s = read s :: Int
```

Comment: You should use an `fmap (map parsePair)` here

Comment: Instead of the non-working `arr <- map parsePair $ replicateM size getLine` you can use the similar `arr <- map parsePair <$> replicateM size getLine` (`<$>` is `fmap`).

Comment: Consider also `replicateM size getLine >>= print . map parsePair`

Comment: see [`do` notation primer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891) with a [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKZgV.jpg), by user:[pigworker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/828361/pigworker)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the type of `replicateM size getLine` is `IO [String]`, it is not a list of `String`s, it is basically a description of an `IO` action that will obtain a `[String]`. You can see the arrow `<-` in an `IO` monad as a way to retrieve it and unpack the result.

You can however do some processing on that like, since `IO` is a `Functor` as well, you can make use of `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`:

```
main :: IO [Int]
main = do
  let size = 3
  fmap (map parsePair) (replicateM size getLine)
```

or you can shift the `fmap` to the `getLine` part:

```
main :: IO [Int]
main = do
  let size = 3
  replicateM size (fmap parsePair getLine)
```

Note that there is a [**`readLn :: Read a => IO a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:readLn) function that is basically `fmap read getLine` (except that it does some addional error handling). We can thus use:

```
main :: IO [Int]
main = do
  let size = 3
  replicateM size readLn
```

Comment: Thanks for the details.
But I’d like to understand why it works without `fmap` if I just do that on the next line

Comment: @Albizia: as said, because the arrow `<-` will obtain the result from that `IO a`. It is not the new line here, it is the fact that you used `arr <- ...`, and then processed the `arr`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn’t understand that part of the answer. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Note that the `do` syntax with the `<-` symbol is really not like the assignment operator (which is `=` in many languages, sometimes `:=` and sometimes indeed `<-`, e.g. in R). Rather, it's a special construct that *executes a monadic action* and extracts the *result* of this action. There is is a fundamental distinction between an action and its result; and often-quoted analogy is that an action is like a *recipe* for a cake, the result is the cake itself.

applying `map parsePair` directly to the `IO` action would be like taking a knife to cut the recipe in pieces, and expecting that you can then use that recipe to bake a ready-cut cake. Clearly that's not how it works.

Likewise, you first need to execute (*bind*) an `IO` action before you can manipulate the result. That's what happens on the line `arr <- replicateM size getLine`: the action is executed and only its result stored in `arr`, so that you can then write `map parsePair arr`.

Alternatively, you can use the `fmap` operator. What this does is basically, it takes a recipe and some instruction what to do with the result, and then adds that instruction to the end of the recipe. If you then execute *that* recipe, the result of it will indeed be a cake cut into pieces.