# Haskell IO : Printing Command Line Arguments

Tags: haskell, io, command-line-arguments, monads, do-notation

I have this program which just prints out the command line arguments.

```
echoArgs :: IO ()
echoArgs = do
        line <- getArgs
        print line
```

What I wanted to know is that why does this fail when I type:

```
echoArgs :: IO ()
echoArgs = do
            line <- getArgs
            putStrLn line
```

and also why doesn't it work when I change it to:

```
echoArgs :: IO String
    echoArgs = do
                line <- getArgs
                let line' = read line :: String
                putStrLn line'
```

Comment: Paying attention to the error messages you receive can be helpful in determining what went wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Because

```
getArgs :: IO [String]
```

so `line` in `do { line <- getArgs ; ... }` is

```
line    ::    [String]
```

but `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()` expects a `String` argument, *not* a list of `String`s.

Similarly, `read :: Read a => String -> a` also expect a `String` argument, *not* a list of `String`s argument.

See also: [The Guide to Types in `do`-notation, In Vivid Colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891).

Answer (score 1):

`print` *produces* a `String` from whatever argument you give it.

`putStrLn`, on the other hand, *expects* a `String` as an argument. (Indeed, `print = putStrLn . show`.) Similarly, `read` expects a `String` as an argument; in effect, it *deserializes* when what you are trying to do is *serialize* the list.

`getArgs` has type `IO [String]`, which means that `line` is not a `String`, but both `String` and `Show a => [a]` have a `Show` instance which  `print` can use to *make* a `String` out of it.