# Fighting IO when reading a configuration file into Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, monads, file-read, do-notation

I have input data intended for my yet-to-be-written Haskell applications, which reside in a file. I don't update the file. I just need to read the file and feed it into my Haskell function which expects a list of strings. But reading the file of course yields `IO` data objects. I have learned that using the `<-` operation can "take out" somehow the strings packed in an `IO` structure, so I tried this attempt:

```
run :: [String]
run = do
  datadef_content <- readFile "play.txt" -- yields a String
  let datadef = lines datadef_content -- should be a [String]
  return datadef
```

I placed this into a file `play.hs` and loaded it from ghci by

```
:l play
```

To my surprise, I got the error message for the `readFile` line

> ```
>  Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘[]’
>  Expected type: [String]
>    Actual type: IO String
> ```

and for the `return` the error message

> ```
>  Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
>  Expected type: [String]
>    Actual type: [[String]]
> ```

The first seems to indicate that I couldn't get rid of the `IO`, and the last message seems to suggest, that `lines` would return a list of list of strings, which also doesn't make sense to me.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You indeed can not get rid of `IO` (or at least you should try to never do that). There is `unsafeIO`, but that will normally generate more trouble than it solves.

Comment: [`Do`-notation explained, in vivid colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891).

Comment: Don't try to `run :: [String]`. Instead, take the function `foo :: [String] -> blah` that takes the contents of `run` as an argument and convert it to `wrappedFoo :: IO [String] -> blah` using either `fmap` or `(=<<)` as appropriate, then apply it to `run :: IO [String]`.

Comment: Haskell forces you to declare that you perform IO _in the type_, if you actually perform IO. Declaring `run :: [String]` amounts to promising that `run` does no IO, and is a "pure" constant list of strings. If you want to do IO, you need to declare `run :: IO [String]`, telling the compiler that this depends on IO, and that it can be executed multiple times, possibly with different results (if e.g. `"play.txt"` changes its contents).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare `run` to be a `[String]` value. But `return` is not a keyword that provides the return value of a function; it *is* a function, with type `Monad m => a -> m a`. `return datadef` produces a value of type `IO [String]`, which becomes the return value of the function.

The solution is to provide the correct return type for `run`:

```
run :: IO [String]
run = do
    ...
```

`run` can also be defined more succinctly as

```
run = fmap lines (readFile "play.txt")
```

Though the `do` syntax suggests is, there is no way to pull a value *out* of an `IO` action; all you can do is "push" the call to `lines` *into* the action.

Comment: Thank you; I will try it. Do you happen to know a source where I can learn about the meaning of `fmap`? The best i could google is [this description of Data.Functor](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Functor.html), and it is pretty terse and I can't quite understand how it explains your example.

Comment: I tried your approach. Now the declaration of `run` is fine, but does it mean that I have to do all my calculation which uses the content of the file inside the `do` block?

Comment: I found [this](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html) webpage which seems to answer my question.