# Haskell do notation edge case fails to typecheck

Tags: haskell, syntax, do-notation

I'm trying to understand the rules for `do` notation.

Here is some code that typechecks:

```
fff :: Maybe Int
fff = do
    _ <- pure $ Just 100
    (+10)
    <$> Just 50
```

Which is basically `fff = (+10) <$> Just 50`. I would assume the above could would **not** type check - because surely each line should be within the context of `Maybe` which `(+10)` is not.

**Why does the above typecheck?** Here is a simpler example of the above:

```
fff :: Int -> Maybe Int
fff i = do
    (+10)
    <$> Just i
```

Why is the above considered valid syntax? Does that not 'desugar' to:

```
fff i = ((+10) >>= (\i -> fmap (Just i))) i
```

Which indeed gives a typecheck error in ghci.

---

Here is an example that does *not* typecheck following a similar indentation as above:

```
x :: Maybe Int
x = do
  _ <- Just 1
  undefined
  <$> Just 5
```

(Thanks to @cvlad from the FP slack chat for the above example)

Comment: FYI [`Do`-notation explained, in colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891).

Comment: your questions are not about do notation, but about the inner workings of the GHC parser. so it failed to recognize that expression when you broke it into two lines, so what. don't do that without indenting the second line more than the first one! :) and you haven't included the error messages. I expect the errors are telling you about the sub-expressions involved and that way you can see how it read them.

Comment: @WillNess It's a good question. *Why* does the parser/typechecker accept one but not the other?

Comment: Clearly the first one conforms to *some* rule; if you don't know, you don't need to dismiss the question as not worth asking.

Comment: @Chris you've changed the question drastically. your interpretation of the do block as bind code is incorrect: `<$>` is *infix* binary operator.

Comment: `<$> Just i` on its own is ill formed expression.

Comment: Sorry have been staring at this code for a while so I'm a bit brain fried. But I think I've narrowed it down to what my question actually is. 

Essentially I was comparing two blocks of code and figuring out why one was type checking while the other was not.

Comment: So maybe a ghc bug? @WillNess

Comment: no, see my answer. But you don't give an example that fails, now.

Comment: it's hard to chase your changing question. :) next time please don't do that. the code changed, but the answer is the same. the do block *before* the `<$>` is `Maybe t` (because of `Just 1`), and we can't fmap *that*.

Comment: The *do notation* is an abstraction over an abstraction and i believe that it can easily be and in fact should be avoided. When dealing with monads use `>>=` and `>>` with proper indentation and it's as readable and as maintainable as supposedly imperative looking but sometimes deceiving *do notation*. Haskell code doesn't need to look imperative. [Do notation considered harmful](https://wiki.haskell.org/Do_notation_considered_harmful)

Comment: one more thing, in your first code snippet,  `fff = do` // `_ <- pure $ Just 100` // `(+10)` // `<$> Just 50`, if you remove `pure $`, it will fail. because of `pure` the do block can be any monadic type, so to match the `(+10)` it becomes `((->) r) t`, so actually `fff = (\r -> let _ = const (Just 100) r in (+10) r) <$> Just 50` (which is indeed equivalent to  `(+10) <$> Just 50`. "surely each line should be within the context of Maybe which (+10) is not" you missed the `pure` there, which makes the context polymorphic, `Just 100` is just a pure value there.

Answer (score 4):

```
fff :: Int -> Maybe Int
fff i = do
    (+10)
    <$> Just i
```

> Why is the above considered valid syntax?

Because it is parsed as

```
fff i = do {        -- do { A } is just
    (+10) }         --      A
    <$> Just i
```

which is equivalent to

```
fff i =
    (+10) 
    <$> Just i
```

because `<$> Just i` on its own is an invalid expression (so `fff i = ((+10) >>= (\i -> fmap (Just i))) i` is incorrect translation), and that delimits the extent of the `do` block as per the rule quoted in @chi's answer.

Indeed its type is inferred as

```
fff :: Num b => b -> Maybe b
```

You second example works if you add a space before the `<$>` in the last line. Without the space, it is again parsed as

```
inputTest :: FormInput -> IO (Either [String] (Int, Int))
inputTest fi = do {
    allErrors' <- undefined :: IO [String]
    undefined }
    <$> ((liftM2 ) (,) <$> undefined <*> undefined) fi
```

*because `<$> ...` on its own is invalid expression.* Indeed when I add the explicit separators,

```
inputTest2 :: String -> IO (Either [String] (Int, Int))
inputTest2 fi = do {
    allErrors2 <- undefined :: IO [String] ;
    undefined  }
    <$> ((liftM2 ) (,) <$> undefined <*> undefined) fi
```

I get the *exact same error message* on TIO (had to use `String` instead of your type there).

Since the first `undefined :: IO [String]`, the whole do block has some `IO t` type, and we can't fmap *that* over anything.

Always add all the explicit separators (in addition to practicing good indentation style), to avoid this weird syntax brittleness.

---

Your new example is

```
x :: Maybe Int
x = do          -- {     this is
  _ <- Just 1   -- ;       how it is
  undefined     -- }         parsed
  <$> Just 5
```

The code changed, but the answer is the same. The `do` block *before* the `<$>` is `Maybe t` (because of `Just 1`), and we can't fmap *that*.

Again, indent the last line some more and it'll compile, because `undefined <$> Just 5` will now be parsed as one expression.

Answer (score 4):

This is a weird interaction.

I started to simplify the test case to this, which runs fine.

```
> x = do succ ; <$> Just 1
> x
Just 2
```

By comparison, this does NOT parse:

```
> y = do { succ ; <$> Just 1 }      
error: parse error
```

However, this parses:

```
> z = do { succ } <$> Just 1      
> z
Just 2
```

So, here's what I think is going on. Since token `<$>` can never start an expression, parse tentatively fails. The `do` parser rule is, essentially, a maximum munch rule: on a fail, add an implicit `}` and try again.

Because of this, `x` above is parsed as `z`. Since `succ` is a monadic value (line `(+10)` in OP's question) it can appear inside `do`. This makes type check succeed.

Quoting the [Haskell Report 2.7](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html)

> A close brace is also inserted whenever the syntactic category
>   containing the layout list ends; that is, if an illegal lexeme is
>   encountered at a point where a close brace would be legal, a close
>   brace is inserted.

Comment: `do 1` parses as does `do "1"`. so it doesn't even need to be a monadic value.