# I'm really confused about function declarations in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, syntax, equality, definition

This is a homework, so I would prefer only tips or a link to where I can learn rather than a full answer.  This is what I am given:

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

What I understand from this is that I am supposed to compare 3 values (in this case `a`, `a`, `a`?) and return whether or not they all equal one another. This is what I tried:

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z do
  Bool check <- x == y
  Bool nextC <- y == z
  if check == nextC
    then True
    else False
```

I honestly feel completely lost with Haskell, so any tips on how to read functions or declare them would help immensely.

Comment: What exactly confuses you about the declaration?

Comment: `a`, `a`, `a` are not the values, but the *types* of the values (i.e., all values have the same type).

Comment: The type signature is correct. And then.. perhaps it's a good idea if you read first few chapters of [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) like [Baby's first functions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#babys-first-functions) for sure...

Comment: Concerning the logic you were trying to implement (I don't know that much Haskell to be able to tell if it actually compiles), consider: What would your function currently return if the values were `x=1`, `y=2`, `z=3`?

Comment: You do not need do-notation or `<-` for this. There's a very short translation of "all three being equal is equivalent to `x` being equal to `y` *and* `y` being equal to `z`" in most programming languages, including Haskell.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `if fact then True else False` is equivalent to `fact`, and `if fact then False else True` is equivalent to `not fact`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This question already has several other perfectly good answers explaining how to solve your problem. I don’t want to do that; instead, I will go through each line of your code, progressively correct the problems, and hopefully help you understand Haskell a bit better.

First, I’ll copy your code for convenience:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z do
  Bool check <- x == y
  Bool nextC <- y == z
  if check == nextC
    then True
    else False
```

The first line is the type signature; this is already explained well in other answers, so I’ll skip this and go on to the next line.

The second line is where you are defining your function. The first thing you’ve missed is that you need an equals sign to define a function: function definition syntax is `functionName arg1 arg2 arg3 … = functionBody`, and you can’t remove the `=`. So let’s correct that:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z = do
  Bool check <- x == y
  Bool nextC <- y == z
  if check == nextC
    then True
    else False
```

The next error is using `do` notation. `do` notation is notorious for confusing beginners, so don’t feel bad about misusing it. In Haskell, `do` notation is only used in specific situations where it is necessary to execute a sequence of statements line by line, and especially when you have some side-effect (like, say, printing to the console) which is executed with each line. Clearly, this doesn’t fit here — all you’re doing is comparing some values and returning a result, which is hardly something which requires line-by-line execution. So let’s get rid of that `do`:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z =
  let Bool check = x == y
      Bool nextC = y == z
  in
    if check == nextC
      then True
      else False
```

(I’ve also replaced the `<-` binding with `let … in …`, since `<-` can only be used within a `do` block.)

Next, another problem: `Bool check` is not valid Haskell! You may be familiar with this syntax from other languages, but in Haskell, a type is always specified using `::`, and often with a type signature. So I’ll remove `Bool` before the names and add type signatures instead:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z =
  let check :: Bool
      check = x == y
      nextC :: Bool
      nextC = y == z
  in
    if check == nextC
      then True
      else False
```

Now, at this point, your program is perfectly valid Haskell — you’ll be able to compile it, and it will work. But there’s still a few improvements you can make.

For a start, you don’t need to include types — Haskell has type inference, and in most cases it’s fine to leave types out (although it’s traditional to include them for functions). So let’s get rid of the types in the `let`:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z =
  let check = x == y
      nextC = y == z
  in
    if check == nextC
      then True
      else False
```

Now, `check` and `nextC` are only used in one place — giving them names doesn’t do anything, and only serves to make the code less readable. So I’ll inline the definitions of `check` and `nextC` into their usages:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z =
  if (x == y) == (y == z)
    then True
    else False
```

Finally, I see you have an expression of the form `if <condition> then True else False`. This is redundant — you can simply return the `<condition>` with the same meaning. So let’s do that:

```hs
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z = (x == y) == (y == z)
```

This is much, much better than the code you started with!

(There is actually one more improvement that you can make to this code. At this point, it should be obvious that your code has a bug. Can you find it? And if so, can you fix it? Hint: you can use the `&&` operator to ‘and’ two booleans together.)

Comment: [tag:do-notation] doesn't have to be hard for newbies; it could (*should?!*) be introduced [axiomatically](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A849891+axiomatically), even [with pictures in vivid colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891)! :) esp. when we consider how self-explanatory List Comprehensions are, and how similar the  Monad Comprehensions are which are nearly equivalent to `do`.

Comment: @WillNess Good point that it’s not hard. (I learnt it fairly easily myself.) I suppose I should have said that it’s notorious for ‘confusing newcomers’ rather than for being ‘tricky to understand’ — I’ll edit that in now.

Comment: yes, confusing, by the confusing presentations always speaking of monads and syntax desugarings...

Comment: @WillNess I’m of the opinion that those presentations are really the only way to learn `do`-notation properly — be careful to avoid the [monad tutorial fallacy](https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2009/01/12/abstraction-intuition-and-the-monad-tutorial-fallacy/)! But, if you’re not happy with my wording, what do you recommend saying? (I just wanted to acknowledge the fact that newcomers to Haskell often seem to misunderstand when to use `do`-notation.)

Comment: Glad you like it. Thanks for the correction @WillNess!

Comment: actually it was all right even before the edit. :) --- personally, for me the most confusing part about do always was the omission of explicit separators (and even parens around lambdas). if it's a programmable semicolon, let there be semicolons, for Pete's sake! :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with a function that takes a single `Int`:

```
allEqual1Int :: Int -> Bool
allEqual1Int x = True

allEqual1Int' :: Int -> Bool
allEqual1Int' x = 
  if x == x
  then True
  else False
```

If we compare that to your line

```
allEqual x y z do
```

we notice that you miss a `=` and that you don't need a `do`.

A version for `String` could look like

```
allEqual1String' :: String -> Bool
allEqual1String' x = 
  if x == x
  then True
  else False
```

and we observe that *the same implementation* works for multiple types (`Int` and `String`) provided they support `==`.

Now `a` is a type variable, think of it as a variable such that its value is a type. And the requirement that the given type supports `==` is encoded in the [`Eq a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Eq.html) constraint (Think of it as an interface). Therefore

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

works for *any* such type that supports `==`.

Answer (score 3):

Haskell is a bit strange language for those who programmed in different languages before. Let's first have a look at this function:

```
allEqual :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
```

You can look at this like that: the last "thing" after "`->`" is a return type. Previews "things" are parameters. From that, we know the function accepts three parameters that are `Int` and returns the `Bool`.

Now have a look at your function.

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

There is an extra syntax "`Eq a =>`". What it basically does is all the following "`a`" in declaration must implement `Eq`. So it is a more generalized version of the first function. It accepts three parameters that implement "`Eq`" and returns `Bool`. What the function should probably do is check if all values are equal.

Now let's have a look at your implementation. You are using a do syntax. I feel like it is not the best approach in the beginning. Let's implement a very similar function which checks if all parameters are equal to 3.

```
allEq3 :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Bool
allEq3 x y z = isEq3 x && isEq3 y && isEq3 z
  where
    isEq3 :: Int -> Bool
    isEq3 x = x == 3
```

Like in your example, we have three parameters, and we return `Bool`. In the first line, we call function `isEq3` on all the parameters. If all these calls return true `allEq3` will also return true. Otherwise, the function will return false. Notice that the function `isEq3` is defined below after the keyword "where". This is a very common thing in Haskell.

So what we did here is taking a big problem of checking if all the parameters are equal to 3 and divide it into smaller pieces which check whether a value is equal to 3.

You can improve this implementation a lot but I think this is the best way to take the first steps in Haskell. If you really want to learn this language you should have a look at [this](http://learnyouahaskell.com/).

Answer (score 2):

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
```

The signature says: `allEqual` consumes 3 values of type `a`; it produces a result  of type `Bool`. The `Eq a =>` part limits the possible operations `a` can have; it says whatever type `a` is, it needs to satisfy the requirements defined in `Eq`.  You can find those requirements here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Eq 
You now know what operations `a` can do, you can then complete your function by following the type signature.

Comment: "limits" is the wrong choice of words. it's exactly the opposite: the constraint *prescribes* the operations that `a` *must* have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it:

```
allEqual :: Eq a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
allEqual x y z = x == y && y == z
```

## What does this mean?

The first line defines the function's *type signature*.

In human words, it would say something like:

> There is a function called `allEqual` for any type `a`. It requires an instance of `Eq a`* and takes three parameters, all of type `a`, and returns a `Bool`

The second line says:

> The function `allEqual`, for any parameters `x`, `y`, and `z`, should evaluate `x == y && y == z`, which simply compares that `x` equals `y` and `y` equals `z`.

* Instances or type classes are a language feature that not many other programming languages have, so if you're confused to what they mean I'd suggest learning about them first.

Comment: OP asked for "I would prefer only tips or a link to where I can learn rather than a full answer". I think you should not provide the full answer.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Allthough you are right, this would mean asking for recommendations, which is discouraged on StackOverflow. Questions should have definitive, clear answers.

Comment: Note that a) I did not downvote b) this entirely your call, I just gave my opinion. Thank you for contributing.