# Conditional change of State in Haskell

Tags: if-statement, haskell, monads, state-monad, do-notation

I don't know how I can make a conditional change to State Monad in Haskell.
Suppose, I have a stack on State Monad.

```
import Control.Monad.State

push :: Int -> State [Int] ()
push x = state $ \xs -> ((), x : xs)

pop :: State [Int] Int
pop = state $ \(x : xs) -> (x, xs)
```

And with that, I want to write a function changing it.

```
someFunc :: Bool -> Int -> State [Int] ()
someFunc b x = do 
  let someValue = x * x
  if b then
    p <- pop
    someValue = someValue + p
  push $ someValue
```

For example, I want to take a bool `b` and a value `x`. And if `b` is `True` (for example, it could be a condition that my stack is not empty) I want to `pop` a value from my stack and add it to some variable. Otherwise, I don't add anything to the variable and just push it into the stack.

How can I achieve this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Haskell, every `if` needs an `else`, since everything is just a value. Also, you can't do `if ... then p <- pop ...` since the `do` notation is lost in an `if` statement, so you need to restart it with `if ... then do p <- pop ...`.

```hs
import Control.Monad.State

push :: a -> State [a] ()
push x = state $ \xs -> ((), x : xs)

pop :: State [a] a
pop = state $ \(x : xs) -> (x, xs)

someFunc :: (Num a) => Bool -> a -> State [a] ()
someFunc b x = do
  let baseValue = x * x
  someValue <- if b then do
        p <- pop
        return $ baseValue + p
      else do
        return baseValue
  push $ someValue
```

Comment: For monadic actions, `ifs` don't fundamentally need `else`s - the `when` function will conditionally execute an action. the problem in @Heir's code is something else entirely - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the smallest fix:

```
someFunc :: Bool -> Int -> State [Int] ()
someFunc b x = do 
  let someValue = x * x
  if b then
    do { p <- pop
       ; push $ someValue + p }
  else
    push $ someValue
```

Both branches of the `if` expression must have the same type, and inside the `do` notation that must be some monadic value type belonging to the same monad as does the overall `do` block; specifically the type of the overall `do` block if that `if` expression is the last one in it.

See also:

- [`do` notation tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/do-notation/info)
- [`do` notation explained, in vivid colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11326549/849891)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the question you asked, how to conditionally execute a monadic action without an `else` clause, there is another problem with your code. You want to reassign a let-variable inside a conditional clause.

This point has been addressed by the other answers, with correct versions of the code. I will elaborate here. All let-variables are immutable, including inside monads. You *can* redefine a variable in a monad, but that merely hides the original variable from code further down the *same* monadic action. The reassignment of `someValue` takes place inside a nested monadic action (there's a new `do` block) and is not visible outside of the `if`.

Conditionally **reassigning** a let-variable is fundamentally impossible. The compiler needs to know at compile time which value is being referred to. Ways to do this are either to `return` a value from the conditional and then assign the variable, like @Aplet123's answer, or run the action in both branches of the conditional on different values, as @Will Ness said.

In reply to the question as stated: you can conditionally run a monadic action (with no `else` branch) using the `when` function from `Control.Monad`. So if your code *really* had no `else` branch, you could write it like this:

```
someFunc :: Bool -> Int -> State [Int] ()
someFunc b x = do 
  let someValue = x * x
  when b $ do
    p <- pop
    push $ someValue + p
```

Of course this makes no sense for pure values, since a value must always be provided. But it does make sense for a monadic action (yielding `()`, or we have the same problem: what is the return value in case of a false conditional?) to be conditionally executed.

Just for curiousity, `when` is defined as follows:

```
when :: (Applicative f) => Bool -> f () -> f ()
when p s  = if p then s else pure ()
```

So `pure ()` serves as the 'null' monadic action.

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: so in the end `when` is itself defined with an `if`! :)